# how Import CSV to MySQL With the matched coloumn name in the mysql table

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I have a table contact it has 35 columns like (name,age,mobile,nationality,gender,email,city,area,etc...),i my cvs  have only name,mobile,nationality,city i want to match the data with the mysql coloumn and insert the cvs data into the specific coloumns in mysql .in cvs file i have more than 100k data its difficult to insert one by one

Is there anyway for me to do this

i tired like this but its not working

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'Book1.csv'
INTO TABLE t1
(@dummy,@dummy,name, @dummy, nationality, mobile1, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy,twon,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy)
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES' at line 4

Comment: Problem is you are putting more than 12 columns.

Comment: i added more column in database now and i tried now i am having 34

Comment: In that case you have mentioned 35 columns. Check your code properly. that's why you are getting error.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the answer you are looking for, but there are faster ways of doing the import if you are only doing it a few times. Rather than doing it by code, you can do it with a simple program like Navicat or HeidiSQL. They both have an easy to use GUI.

Comment: Load data infile at the command line is the fastest approach. If you have millions or rows, you really wouldn't want to go near a GUI.

Comment: I completely agree. That's why I said if he is only doing it a few times.